# How to deploy an RubyGem-based Server

Tags: ruby, deployment, rubygems

We have built a custom socket server in ruby and packaged it as a gem.  Since this is an internal project we can not simply publish it to RubyForge or GitHub.  I tried to setup our own gem server but gem would not authenticate over https. Our other deployment is all for standard rails applications that use capistrano and svn for deployment.

Our current setup which is to use a rails-like deployment with capistrano. which does the following:

- Check out the code from svn
- Build the gem
- Install the gem
- Restart the server

This just seems awkward, and makes the gem packaging seem like extra work -- but outside of the deployment issue it fits really nicely as a gem.

Is there a cleaner approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start

```
gem server #That will serve all your local installed gems.

gem install YourLocalPkg1.X.X.gem
```

#on YourHost

use

```
gem sources --add localhost:8808
gem install YourGem
```

on client machine
develop something

```
rake gem
gem install YourLocalPkg2.X.X.gem #on YourHost
```

use

```
gem update YourGem #on client machine
```

Maybe you have a need to use https but I don't see why  in your post.
On Some Machine

```
* Check out the code from svn #the railspart not in the gem
* gem update  YourGem #  or install if not exist....
* Restart the server
```

Comment: @Dolphin you mean the 'gem sources --add http://localhost:8808' and that gem server supposedly runs on 8808 ? Not to mention "Gem in a Box" gem.

Comment: I meant if you want to share your local gems you run command `gem server` instead of `gem_server`. Of course gem in a box would be better solution for most situations.

Answer (score 2):

You can install gems from the local filesystem.

```
gem install /path/to/some.gem
```

Shouldn't be too hard for you to script scp with that, or use an NFS mount, etc.

Answer (score 0):

gem install --local path_to_gem/filename.gem will help. Or you can get a trusted certificate on your web server.

You might be able to install from the server with gem install -P NoSecurity or -P LowSecurity, but I haven't tried that.

http://www.rubygems.org/read/chapter/21